# Where to find dev jobs for film?

Tags: job-search

I always see in movie credits that there's usually an IT team. Often there's developers too.

How does one get into one of these positions? Where can you apply?

I take it it might be through an agency or some contract work.

Thanks!

Comment: *"Where can you apply?"* - uhmm... you apply... at those companies? Google them, see if they have job offers available and apply... or perhaps you wanted to ask something else

Comment: Is there an IT SE forum that would better suit this?

Comment: @MichaelMcFarlane the post is about job applications so I believe TWP is a good fit

Answer (score 4):

For each movie:

1. Pause the credits on "IT Team".
2. Write down the names of the IT Team, and/or the company name.
3. Search each name on the internet (e.g., LinedIn). Collect a list of IT contractors that serve the industry.
4. Reach out to those companies with your resume and intentions.

Answer (score 3):

Start with the large film studios: Universal, Technicolor, Warner Brothers, etc. At least in Hollywood the rules of whose name gets on the credits (and whose doesn't) is tightly controlled by union contracts and subject of intense negotiation. If that bit is important to you, I suggest to reach out to the local Unions and get up to speed on how this works.